# How to set multiple proxies in Selenium Webdriver Java

Tags: java, selenium, automation, webdriver, automated-tests

My requirement is for opening my project site it requires two different proxies.
How to handle it with Selenium Webdriver?

Please help me.

Comment: what kind of proxy? ssl? http? ftp? socks?

Comment: http proxy i want to set.. as per my requirement my both proxies are http proxies which i have to set.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned what driver you are using(Firefox, Chrome, ..)but this is how you do it for Firefox:

```
        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
        profile.setEnableNativeEvents(true);

        profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http_port", proxyPort);
        profile.setPreference("network.proxy.ssl", proxyHost);
        profile.setPreference("network.proxy.ssl_port", proxyPort);

        FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Comment: i am using firefox driver and requirement is using http proxy and proxy are two IPs. how it will work?

Comment: I do not think there is a way you can define multiple proxies in FF itself. There might be some add-ons that allow this but not plain FF and hence not with Webdriver. The best solution here will probably be external to FF. For example proxy chaining...

Comment: yes you are right, manually we can't set multiple proxies in FF for this we are using proxifier. but not able to do it with webdriver. can u plz help me how to use proxy chaining in automation through webdriver